# Suppress a page break before a breakable tcolorbox

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

I'm trying to avoid page breaks between a sectioning command and a following tcolorbox. With "normal" boxes I can use `\nopagebreak`, e.g. in the `before` option:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum,needspace}
\tracingpages=1
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[before=\nopagebreak,
                  %breakable, %
                  ]
\rule{1cm}{10\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

But this fails if I activate the `breakable` option. There is a break point that I can't identify. Has someone an idea where it is and how I can suppress it? `\Needspace` helps but one has to know the size of objects at the begin of the tcolorbox.

Comment: That's a tricky problem. A breakable box tests if there is enough space on the current page to place the first box part. In your case, there is not enough space. Thus a `\pagebreak` is inserted and splitting starts at the next page. This is fine in most situations, but here a lonely heading is left behind. I do not have an automatic solution for that; one has to put a `\pagebreak` before the heading by hand in this situation (or make this box `unbreakable`).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: A forced pagebreak before the section is not an option - it is quite possible that there is enough room on the page. What works is something like `before=\if@nobreak\enlargethispage{-5cm}\fi,` or `\if@nobreak\vspace{5cm}\null\vspace{-5cm}\fi`  but inside `\tcb@split@first` the `\enlargethispage` (and the test) no longer works. Is there a place where the size needed for the first split is already known and where one could insert an `\enlargethispage` or the `\vspace` with a sensible value?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Another idea: could tcolorbox write some informations (minimal size of first block etc) to the aux-file or somewhere else? Then I could use this information in suitable \needspace commands.

Comment: In this case, the minimal size of the first block is unknown because the rule makes it larger than the available space. It stays unknown and the situation is detected by receiving an empty first block. I could save the available space, but after using this information, the space will have changed and I guess we will end with a neverending ping-pong algorithm.

Comment: Maybe, I could implement a warning for the least if a page break happens even if `\@nobreaktrue` is set. Also, a minimal space after a heading could be checked if a `tcolorbox` follows; something like `\if@nobreak\vspace{5cm}\null\vspace{-5cm}\fi` you mentioned before. This would not prevent the critical situation completely, but it will become more unlikely. On the other side, small boxes may flush to the next page more often (but with the heading).

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: If there were a marker in the box like `\firstbreaknotbeforehere` (I will have to think about a good name ...) could you then retrieve the distance from top to the marker and store it?

Comment: I would'nt know how to do that :-( But I added an answer with a patch now. You can try if this is helpful.

Comment: @Thomas F. Sturm: I quite certain that your code is useful but couldn't test it yet  - I hope to be able to do it today.

Comment: I was not sure if I have overlooked something :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The following patch can be used for `tcolorbox` version `3.32` and prior. It is incorporated in [`tcolorbox` version `3.33 (2014/12/11)`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) and higher. To revert to the old behavior before `3.33`, the option `ignore nobreak` can be applied.

As I wrote in my comments, I fear that there is no global solution for the problem. But I experimented with a patch which might be helpful for many use cases. The patch code tries to estimate the space needed after a heading. If it is very probable that the box or the first part of the box does not fit on the current page, the `\vspace{...}\null\vspace{-...}` trick of yours is applied to move everything to the next page including the heading.

The space estimation can fail especially, if the box contains a large unbreakable content as in your example. In this case, a warning is given to detect such problems in long documents. One manual solution is to enlarge the `lines before break` value to match the unbreakable content. Currently, I do not see an automatic way.

The following code is an experimental patch. If it prooves to be stable, I want to put it into an official version, but there have to be many tests before that. If you see (new) problems with it or if you can improve it, feel free to comment. The main part is `\tcb@handle@nobreak`, the rest is some slightly changed current code.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tracingpages=1

\makeatletter

\def\tcb@do@nobreak@warning{%
  \tcb@warning{Using nobreak failed. Try to enlarge `lines before break' or set page breaks manually}%
}

\def\tcb@handle@nobreak{%
  \tcb@enlbreak@init%
  \tcb@breakat@init%
  \tcb@comp@h@page%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\tcb@h@page-\baselineskip}% security surcharge
  \tcb@comp@h@total@standalone%
  \tcb@check@for@final@box%
  \iftcb@final@box%
  \else%
    \ifdim\dimexpr\tcb@h@page-\tcb@h@padding-\tcb@h@padtitle<\kvtcb@breakminlines\baselineskip\relax%
      \tcbdimto\tcb@h@page{\tcb@h@page+3\baselineskip}%
      \vspace{\tcb@h@page}%
      {\parskip\z@\nointerlineskip\noindent}%
      \vspace{-\tcb@h@page}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\def\tcb@prepare@break@operation{%
  \let\tcb@nobreak@warning\@empty%
  \@ifundefined{columnbreak}{\tcb@multicolfalse}{%
    \ifnum\doublecol@number>\z@ %
      \tcb@multicoltrue%
    \else%
      \tcb@multicolfalse%
    \fi}%
  \ifx\kvtcb@float\@empty%
    \if@nobreak%
      \tcb@handle@nobreak%
      \let\tcb@nobreak@warning\tcb@do@nobreak@warning%
    \else%
      \kvtcb@beforebox%
    \fi%
    \def\kvtcb@beforebox{\parskip\z@\nointerlineskip\noindent}%
    \noindent% applies parskip
    \vskip\lineskip{\parskip\z@\par\vskip\z@}\bgroup\@nobreakfalse\addpenalty\z@\egroup% force update vertical list
    \tcb@break@allowedtrue%
    \tcb@enlbreak@init%
  \else%
    \tcb@break@allowedfalse%
  \fi%
}


\def\tcb@split@start{%
  \tcb@breakat@init%
  \tcb@comp@h@page%
  % height calculation
  \tcb@comp@h@total@standalone%
  %
  \let\tcb@split@next=\relax%
  \tcb@check@for@final@box%
  \iftcb@final@box%
    \tcb@drawcolorbox@standalone%
  \else
    \iftcb@break@allowed%
      \ifdim\dimexpr\tcb@h@page-\tcb@h@padding-\tcb@h@padtitle<\kvtcb@breakminlines\baselineskip\relax%
        \iftcb@multicol\columnbreak\else\pagebreak\fi%
        \tcb@nobreak@warning%
        \tcb@enlbreak@init\tcb@break@allowedfalse%
        \tcb@comp@h@page%
        \tcb@check@for@final@box%
        \iftcb@final@box%
          \tcb@drawcolorbox@standalone%
        \else
          \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@first%
        \fi
      \else%
        \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@first%
      \fi
    \else%
      \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@first%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \tcb@split@next%
}


\def\tcb@split@first{%
  \setcounter{tcbbreakpart}{1}%
  \ifx\kvtcb@float\@empty%
    \iftcb@vfillbeforefirst%
      \let\tcb@before@first=\vfill%
    \else%
    \let\tcb@before@first=\@empty%
    \fi%
    \let\tcb@before@middle=\@empty%
    \let\tcb@before@last=\@empty%
    \iftcb@multicol%
      \long\def\tcb@after@first{\par}% using \columnbreak here kills multicols' algortihm sometimes
      \long\def\tcb@after@middle{\par\vfill}%
    \else%
      \long\def\tcb@after@first{\par\pagebreak\tcb@enlbreak@next}%
      \long\def\tcb@after@middle{\par\vfill\eject\tcb@enlbreak@next}%
    \fi%
    \let\tcb@after@last=\par%
  \else%
    \edef\tcb@before@first{\noexpand\tcb@float@env@begin{tcbfloat}[\kvtcb@float]\noexpand\kvtcb@everyfloat}%
    \let\tcb@before@middle=\tcb@before@first%
    \let\tcb@before@last=\tcb@before@first%
    \let\tcb@after@first=\tcb@float@env@end%
    \let\tcb@after@middle=\tcb@float@env@end%
    \let\tcb@after@last=\tcb@float@env@end%
  \fi%
  %
  \edef\kvtcb@skin@@first{\kvtcb@skin@first}%
  \edef\kvtcb@skin@@middle{\kvtcb@skin@middle}%
  \edef\kvtcb@skin@@last{\kvtcb@skin@last}%
  %
  \let\tcb@h@breaksep@first=\kvtcb@bottomsep%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@h@breaksep@middle{\kvtcb@bottomsep+\kvtcb@topsep}%
  \let\tcb@h@breaksep@last=\kvtcb@topsep%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@h@padding@first{\kvtcb@bbtop@stand+\kvtcb@bbbottom@break+\kvtcb@top@rule@stand+\kvtcb@bottom@rule@break+\tcb@h@breaksep@first+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@top+\kvtcb@bottom}%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@h@padding@middle{\kvtcb@bbtop@break+\kvtcb@bbbottom@break+\kvtcb@top@rule@break+\kvtcb@bottom@rule@break+\tcb@h@breaksep@middle+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@top+\kvtcb@bottom}%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@h@padding@last{\kvtcb@bbtop@break+\kvtcb@bbbottom@stand+\kvtcb@top@rule@break+\kvtcb@bottom@rule@stand+\tcb@h@breaksep@last+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@top+\kvtcb@bottom}%
  %
  \tcb@split@setstate@first%
  %
  \splittopskip=0pt%
  \splitmaxdepth=0pt%
  \edef\tcb@thevfuzz{\the\vfuzz}%
  \edef\tcb@thevbadness{\the\vbadness}%
  %
  \tcb@swap{\tcb@totalupperbox}{\tcb@upperbox}%
  \tcb@swap{\tcb@totallowerbox}{\tcb@lowerbox}%
  %
  \let\tcb@split@next=\relax%
  \tcbdimto\tcb@split@dim{\tcb@h@page-\tcb@h@padding@first-\tcb@h@padtitle}%
  \ifdim\tcb@split@dim<\tcb@h@upper\relax%
    \tcb@split@upper@box%
    \ifdim\wd\tcb@totalupperbox=0pt\relax%
      \iftcb@lowerspace%
        \tcb@sdraw@U%
        \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@SL%
      \else%
        \tcb@split@force@standalone%
        \tcb@drawcolorbox@standalone%
      \fi%
    \else%
      \ifdim\dimexpr\tcb@h@upper=0pt\relax%
        \iftcb@break@allowed
          \tcb@swap{\tcb@totalupperbox}{\tcb@upperbox}%
          \tcb@swap{\tcb@totallowerbox}{\tcb@lowerbox}%
          \tcbdimto\tcb@h@upper{\ht\tcb@upperbox+\dp\tcb@upperbox}%
          \tcbdimto\tcb@h@lower{\ht\tcb@lowerbox+\dp\tcb@lowerbox}%
          \iftcb@multicol\columnbreak\else\pagebreak\fi%
          \tcb@nobreak@warning%
          \tcb@enlbreak@init\tcb@break@allowedfalse%
          \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@start%
        \else%
          \tcb@sdraw@U%
          \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@USL%
        \fi%
      \else%
        \tcb@sdraw@U%
        \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@USL%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \tcb@swap{\tcb@totalupperbox}{\tcb@upperbox}%
    \tcbdimto\tcb@split@dim{\tcb@split@dim-\tcb@h@upper-\tcb@h@segment}
    \ifdim\tcb@split@dim<\kvtcb@breakminlines\baselineskip\relax%
      \tcb@sdraw@U%
      \iftcb@lowerspace%
      \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@SL%
      \else%
      \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@USL%
      \fi%
    \else
      \tcb@split@lower@box%
      \ifdim\wd\tcb@totallowerbox=0pt\relax%
        \tcb@split@force@standalone%
        \tcb@drawcolorbox@standalone%
      \else%
        \tcb@sdraw@USL%
        \let\tcb@split@next=\tcb@split@L%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \tcb@split@next%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,%
                  lines before break=10,% commenting this issues a warning
                  ]
\rule{1cm}{10\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}


\clearpage
\lipsum[1-4]

\rule{1cm}{6mm}

\section{Normal case}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have now tried the patch with a rather large document with a lots of boxes and it reduced around 20 occurences of such breaks to one - and gave a neat warning in the log about it. So it looks quite promising.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good to hear. Currently, I'm doing further tests myself to ensure stability.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm was this merged into the main implementation?  Thanks for all your work!

Comment: @Clément Yes, since `version 3.33 (2014/12/11)`