# Avoid orphaned mdframed box after section heading at end of page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, mdframed, thmtools, widows-orphans

In LaTeX, when I use thmtools (which uses mdframed internally) to create theorem boxes and I use them after a section heading at the end of the page, they often times are placed on the next page without the heading:

[image: example]

How can I avoid this behaviour, so that the section heading is pulled to the next page? Here is some code to experiment with to generate the boxes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm} %math
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %more colors

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=10pt,skipbelow=5pt}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries\sffamily\color{ForestGreen!70!black}, bodyfont=\normalfont,
  headpunct={}, notebraces={}{}, headpunct={\nopagebreak\newline}, %postheadspace={},
  mdframed={
      linewidth=2pt, needspace=8em,
      rightline=false, topline=false, bottomline=false,
      linecolor=ForestGreen, backgroundcolor=ForestGreen!5,
    }
]{thmgreenbox}

\declaretheorem[style=thmgreenbox, name=Definition, numbered=no]{definition}


\begin{document}
asdf

\vspace{\paperheight-30em}

\section{asdf}

\begin{definition}[t-Test]
  $ X_1, \ldots , X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) $ seien unabhängig und identisch verteilt mit unbekannter Varianz $ \sigma^2 $
  $$
    T = \frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{s / \sqrt{n}}
  $$
  ist $ t $-verteilt mit $ (n - 1) $ Freiheitsgraden
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `needspace`-property from the mdframed-settings, then only the boxes title is on the previous page, but all of its contents are on the next. I want both, title and at least some of the boxes content on the same page, but together with a section heading.

This problem I believe can occur with any other mdframed-box, not just in thmtools, but it happens less often if you have no title etc.

Comment: you can try with \Needspace before the section title, but basically with mdframed that is very difficult (tcolorbox is much better here, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215541/suppress-a-page-break-before-a-breakable-tcolorbox).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I now added code for an entire file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer does it work out of the box with tcolorbox now or do I need to use all that code provided in the accepted answer in the question you linked?

Comment: needspace  means "if no room, do `\clearpage`" so it is _forcing_ a page break after the heading. You need `\NeedSpace{3cm}` _before_ the section

Comment: the question I linked to is many years old, and the package improved quite a lot in the mean time so check the current tcolorbox documentation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is there any more generic way, like to include something in the boxes definition? because I don't always manually want to check if this happened and if so add a `NeedSpace{3cm}` before the section. This is somewhat annoying. I want it to work automatically.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer alright, then thanks for the recommendation. I will give this package a try then once I find some time to try out.

Comment: well you could append that to `\section` so all headings were that far from the bottom

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot for the recommendation! :) I had time now to set up everything in tcolorbox and it works perfectly! Took me quite a while since this package is so complex, but it really is insanely good!